# Finding numbers in a list using binary search need assistance

Tags: python, list, find, binary-search, slice

```
nums = [734, 533, 449, 69, 869, 965, 656, 145, 913, 874, 987, 315, 967, 707]
nums.sort()
b=int(input("What number are you searching for?(Binary) "))
if b<nums[0] or b>nums[len(nums)-1]:
    print("The number you entered it out of list range")
    quit()
while True:
    if len(nums)==1 and nums[0]!=b:
        print("The number has not been found")
        break
    mid=nums[len(nums)//2]
    if mid==b:
        print("The number has been found")
        break
    elif mid>b:
        nums=nums[:len(nums)//2]
    else:
        nums=nums[len(nums)//2:]
```

This binary search works but my teacher said that he doesn't want me to slice and I don't know what that means. Need help figuring out how to set the left and right bounds.

Comment: `nums[:len(nums)//2]` is slicing. Your teacher probably wants you to use two variables to hold the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I just added the sort function

Comment: Check this out: [Binary search (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81188-binary-search/)

Answer (score 0):

let me give u a little hint

```
mid = (start + end) // 2
if num[mid] > b:
  end = mid
```